# Swift Mac OS: blank page printed when I try to print webView (WKWebView)

Tags: swift, macos, printing, webview, wkwebview

I made a webView present a given HTML string, using this code:

```
let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "my file name", ofType: "html")
let htmlStr = try! NSString.init(contentsOfFile: filePath!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
webView.loadHTMLString(htmlStr as String, baseURL: nil)
```

the `webView` present the HTML correctly but when I try to print it the print panel appear with blank page, I used this:

```
webView.printView(nil)
```

also I tried this:

```
NSPrintOperation(view: webView).run()
```

All appeared print panel with blank page! Any help?

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18216560/webview-osx-not-rendering-in-print-panel-preview?rq=1

Comment: In new Swift no more (mainFrame) property in WKWebView, so how I can convert this to new Swift: NSPrintOperation(view: webView.mainFrame.frameView.documentView).runOperation()

Comment: Read the documentation.  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/webview

Comment: The document says: Starting in iOS 8.0 and OS X 10.10, use WKWebView to add web content to your app. Do not use UIWebView or WebView

Comment: In WKWebView there is no webFrame .. also in documentation there is no explain how to print the webView .. see: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview

Comment: I'm running into this same issue. Have you figured out how to print to PDF on macOS?

Answer (score 0):

run() doesn't work with WKWebView on OSX.  Use runModal(for:delegate:didRun:contextInfo) instead.  Example:

```
let printInfo = NSPrintInfo.shared
printInfo.horizontalPagination = .fit
printInfo.verticalPagination = .automatic
printInfo.isVerticallyCentered = true
printInfo.isHorizontallyCentered = true
printInfo.orientation = .portrait
printInfo.topMargin = 20
printInfo.bottomMargin = 20
printInfo.rightMargin = 20
printInfo.leftMargin = 20

let op = self.webView.printOperation(with: printInfo)
op.showsPrintPanel = true
op.showsProgressPanel = true
op.view?.frame = self.webView.bounds
op.runModal(for: self.view.window!, delegate: self, didRun: nil, contextInfo: nil)
```

I got this from: [How does one Print all WKWebView On AND Offscreen content OSX and iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33319295/)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).